# created html form to edit xml file but cant read php script

Tags: php, html, xml, google-chrome

I created php file to edit xml file from html
but when I run the script in browser ,that code is write as text like this

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzGhH.png)

```
load("place.xml");
$rootTag = $xml - > getElementsByTagName("place") - > item(0);
$dataTag = $xml - > createElement("ano");
$wilayahTag = $xml - > createElement("wilayah", $_REQUEST['wilayah']);
$latitudeTag = $xml - > createElement("latitude", $_REQUEST['latitude']);
$longitudeTag = $xml - > createElement("longitude", $_REQUEST['longitude']);
$descTag = $xml - > createElement("desc", $_REQUEST['desc']);
$dataTag - > appendChild($wilayahTag);
$dataTag - > appendChild($latitudeTag);
$dataTag - > appendChild($longitudeTag);
$dataTag - > appendChild($descTag);
$rootTag - > appendChild($dataTag);
$xml - > save("place.xml");
} ?>
```

with 4 edittext

Here is my code

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Add Location</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['ok'])) {
 $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0");
 $xml->load("place.xml");
 
 $rootTag = $xml->getElementsByTagName("place")->item(0);
 
 $dataTag = $xml->createElement("ano");
 
 $wilayahTag = $xml->createElement("wilayah",$_REQUEST['wilayah']);
 $latitudeTag = $xml->createElement("latitude",$_REQUEST['latitude']);
 $longitudeTag = $xml->createElement("longitude",$_REQUEST['longitude']);
 $descTag = $xml->createElement("desc",$_REQUEST['desc']);
 
 $dataTag->appendChild($wilayahTag);
 $dataTag->appendChild($latitudeTag);
 $dataTag->appendChild($longitudeTag);
 $dataTag->appendChild($descTag);

 $rootTag->appendChild($dataTag);
 
 $xml->save("place.xml");
} 
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="wilayah"/><br>
<input type="text" name="latitude"/><br>
<input type="text" name="longitude"/><br>
<input type="text" name="desc"/>
<input type="submit" name="ok" value="add"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have this on some sort of php server?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the php code that you have entered is not being run as php. This probably means you don't have it located on a server when you opened it. I copied the code onto my server and it did work, displaying just text boxes and no code.
A file named place.xml with a `<place>` xml element must also be provided for this to work.